# SASS Functions with Variables

Tags: sass

I'm fairly new to SASS functions and mixins. I would like to make a SASS function that multiplies a base spacing unit variable based on the number that is provided in the class name.

It would work like this. Say you had a variable called $base-spacing-unit with a value of 10. If you put the class ".pad-top-b5" on an HTML element it would give it a top padding of the $base-spacing-unit x 5.

The function might look something like this:

```
$base-spacing-unit: 10;

@function pad-top-b($val) {
    padding-top: ($base-spacing-unit * $val);
}
```

On the HTML element you could put a class like this:

```
<div class="pad-top-b10"></div>
```

And the element would have a top padding of 100px. Is this even possible with SASS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`@for`](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while#for) loop that generates a set of classes:

```
$class-slug: pad-top-b;
$base-spacing-unit: 10;
$classes-amount: 10;

@for $i from 1 through $classes-amount {
  .#{$class-slug}#{$i} {
    padding-top: ($base-spacing-unit * $i);
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/dc396ff76c7b67412a9b0261854da75c) on SassMeister.